# Why isn't my path2d position updating?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I created a new path2d following the instructions in the my first game article: http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/getting_started/step_by_step/your_first_game.html

I wanted to move the "box" on screen so that I could see how the mobs spawn in, but when I ran the scene, it stayed off screen.

I created a new path2d, centered this one in the middle of the screen, and it works like I wanted it to, but now I moving this one in the editor doesn't update the position in game.

What's going on?

Thanks

```
func _on_mobtimer_timeout():
    $mobtimer.wait_time = 0.1 + randf() / 2
    $mobspawn/moblocation.set_offset(randi())

    var mob = Mob.instance()
    add_child(mob)
    var direction = $mobspawn/moblocation.rotation + PI/2
    mob.position = $mobspawn/moblocation.position
    direction += rand_range(-PI/8, PI/8)
    mob.rotation = direction
    mob.set_linear_velocity(Vector2(rand_range(200, 200 + score * 30), 0).rotated(direction))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your scripts? We cannot help you without them.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your scene tree?

Comment: Thanks, those names match the code. Please see my revised answer for another explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A `Node2D`'s `position` property is relative to it's parent's `position`.  The code from the Dodge The Creeps tutorial assumes that `MobPath` is located at `0, 0` and fails when that assumption is false.

In your case you are taking a `MobSpawnLocation`'s position relative to `MobPath` and then setting it as the new `Mob`'s global position.

Luckily `Node2D`'s have another property that we can use in these circumstances `global_position`. It can be used like this:

```
mob.position = $mobspawn/moblocation.global_position
```

http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node2d.html#member-variables

Comment: That's probably it, but I updated my original post. I'll go through the code and see if that's what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full solution, but I found a weird workaround. Instead of changing the position in the editor, if you use the nodes on the orange box (at the intersection of orange and blue), you can kind of alternate to move the box around.

[image: picture of orange box]